# Multi language support in wireshark

Tags: wireshark

Do we have multiple language support with Wireshark.
We are using Windows Xp SP2 and Ubuntu Linux environment.

Actually we have a plugin which is UDP based and we have a requirement to Analyse the Information in Packet List Pane and Packet Details Pane to be viewed in other languages like French, German, Italian etc ... So is it possible with Wireshark version - 1.2.0.

For e.g.
Can we also have all the Menu Items etc ... all text in Wireshark which is there in English to be seen in French, German and Italian.

Comment: Huh? Is the question about the availability of some API in the context of wireshark plug-in? Or is it something else?

Comment: Now i feel sorry for SuperUser...

Answer (score 2):

Some official WireShark devs have already [answered your question](http://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-dev/200908/msg00308.html).

Comment: What he said. :-)  There's work in progress on a version of Wireshark using Qt rather than GTK+, and there's some internationalization of the menus and the like there, but there are *so* many strings used in the dissectors that the packet summary and details will probably *never* be translated in their entirety, if at all.